# Cocoapods load error. $ pod init -> LoadError

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I installed cocoapos with `$sudo gem install cocoapods` and then entered `$ pod init`

Now I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    14: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:23:in `<module:Pod>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core.rb:38:in `<module:Pod>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- cocoapods-core/specification/json (LoadError)
```

My system:

> macOS 10.15.1
>
> xcode 11.3
>
> Swift version 5.1.3